# Problems with JTDS connection. SQL SERVER

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I need to make the connection between my android application and SQL Server, but am having problems. 
my code is:

```
public class DataBaseConnection {

String connectionUrl;
Connection conn;
String user = "sa";
String password = "xxx";

public boolean openConnection()
{
    connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.30:1433/FleuryV6;";

    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, user, password);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
    }
}
```

When debugging the application, I realized that it returns an exception of DriverManager class:

```
 // If we get here, none of the drivers are able to resolve the URL
    throw new SQLException("No suitable driver", sqlState);
```

Have researched enough, and no longer know what can be the solution, can someone help me?

Comment: Why don't you use web services for database transactions?

Comment: I would like to make a direct connection, because there is already a version of the application that establishes a connection via WEBSERVICES